# How to make multiple DEs less messy? Specifically KDE on Ubuntu

Tags: gnome, kde, desktop-environments

On one of my laptops, I installed all of the popular DEs because I like to experiment with them.  I have Unity, GNOME Shell, KDE, and xfce all installed.  It seems that KDE and GNOME don't "get along", and makes things messed up such as words and characters on the screen.  Also, it appears that some applications get mixed up with each other.  Is there any way to make the DEs less "messy"?  -  Ubuntu 11.10

Also, is there a way to install KDE in a way that DOESN'T install a bunch of other stuff that isn't needed.  Such as the KDE sentences...  They aren't needed since I already have the GNOME applications.  Also, when you install KDE it also changes the shutdown and startup screen to Kubuntu instead of Ubuntu.

In response to a comment on my question, I tried to install KDE-core but I could not find it.  And will installing KDE mess up the fonts in my other DEs?

Comment: I'm using Nautilus (which is drawing the desktop) KDM (Display manager) XFCE panel, and the KDE Plasma desktop perfectly fine. KDE apps are themed by using QT4 Settings, I'm logged into the XFCE session.

Comment: I haven't noticed the xfce application interfering too much with the GNOME apps.  Just KDE.

Comment: Is there a way then to make KDE a bit more integrated into the system?  Or when you go to install kubuntu-desktop, is there some "extras" I don't need to install?

Comment: Ok so just KDE, KDM, and QT4?

Comment: Alright thank you very much, I'm gonna try installing it now.

Comment: I can't find KDE-core on Synaptic

Comment: I don't remember if that it's exact name it's something along those lines, and no KDE doesn't mess fonts.

Comment: I also noticed that after installing xubuntu-desktop that my startup, shutdown, and GRUB screens have changed.  And the speed of my desktop booting as well...

Comment: Xubuntu-desktop is XFCE+ubuntu's extras, XFCE is XFCE alone.

Comment: Yeah I installed it to get the xubuntu experience.

Comment: Another user like me (experimenting with several DEs). @UriHerrera, my experience shows that KDE do something with fonts. It uses `medium` hinting, while gnome uses `slight` hinting, there is the main difference.

Comment: If possible, please consider closing some of your other open questions by [selecting the best answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer) (if they have one). Consider which answers have been useful and need an upvote. We need users to maintain their questions so that the site can be an effective tool for the next person with your problems. For more details on best practices consider reading [the FAQ on asking questions](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you want to experiment with different Desktop Environments it is perhaps best to do that on virtual machines rather than the computer you use all the time.

Each DE installs so many other programs you're bound to get some clashes, and certainly lots of alternative apps you probably don't want (how many office apps do you need?)

Answer (score 0):

Check this page, it shows how to get an uniform look for Gnome and KDE apps
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uniform_Look_for_Qt_and_GTK_Applications

Answer (score 0):

To install KDE without a lot of other stuff, depending on which other stuff you don't want installed, you could probably do:

```
sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install <KDE package name>
```

Answer (score 0):

For plymouth option see [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132120/how-to-recover-splash-screen/132181#132181) too.By this way you can change which logo should come on booting ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You can install only the `kde-plasma-desktop` or `plasma-desktop` package in Ubuntu, they give you the basic desktop environments needed for kde. I think `kde-plasma-desktop` is better, since it is more parent package for `plasma-desktop` and not bigger than it's child (*`plasma-desktop`*).

As for the startup and shutdown screen, enter the following commands in terminal. If you have already installed the `kubuntu-desktop` package.

`sudo apt-get remove plymouth-theme-kubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-kubuntu-text`.

You can also install the packages with names starting with `kde-config-xxxx`, since they provide the volume control, networking_applet, bluetooth and other **system-configuration** functionality for the KDE.

**Don't forget** the `kde-config-gtk` package and `gtk3-engines-oxygen`, `gtk2-engines-oxygen` and optionally `oxygen-molecule`packages. They provide you the uniform *look and feel* in KDE and GNOME. (
Prevents ugly look of Gnome apps, when opened in KDE).

You can install other recommended packages as per your need by

- opening the `synaptic` package manager,
- search for `kubuntu-desktop` package in the search bar,
- right clicking on the package name, pointing the `mark recommended for Installation` list,
- and selecting a package from newly appeared sub-menu.

**Note:** From my experience, I see that, after opening `firefox` in KDE, when you open it again in GNOME, you will get ugly looking font-rendering of `firefox`. This happens because KDE use **Full hinting style**, where Gnome use **Slight hinting style**. To prevent this,

- **delete** the file in your home directory with name `.fonts.conf` after login in Gnome session
- or edit the file with replacing `hintmedium` with value `hintslight`.

Hope this will help.

---

**If don't like to remove kubuntu-logo splash screen**

If you simply want to switch to ubuntu splash screen, you can do this by entering following in `terminal`

`sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth` and selecting `ubuntu-logo.plymouth` by entering associated number. This will restore Ubuntu splash screen.
You must enter `sudo update-initramfs -u` command following the previous command, to save the change.