# How to recover splash screen

Tags: plymouth

I am on 11.04.My Ubuntu splash screen was replaced by Kubuntu after I installed Kubuntu-desktop.I followed the answer of daniel kullmann by mistake in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12394/getting-back-ubuntus-default-boot-splash) askubuntu link and I lost splash screen.Now it shows only a blank screen after boot menu until login screen.I entered the other commands from the same post but changed nothing.How can I get back the splash screen back?

Comment: It didnt work for me....
Lenovo G50-30 Ubuntu 14.04.2 64-bit when i made changes as suggested by0x00f
it shows white screen instead splash screen but boots properly...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

Select the original default and then

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Reboot.

---

If it still doesn't appear then open a terminal and type the following command:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
```

or this command by Alt+F2

```
gksu gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
```

This file may not exist, so you may be creating it from scratch now.
Enter the following content on the file you opened on the previous step:

```
FRAMEBUFFER=y
```

Close and save the file.
Now, run the following command to commit the change:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Reboot and enjoy your Plymouth splash screen.

Comment: The answer still works as of ubuntu 18.04 (in my case I was stuck with the ubuntu budgie logo).

Comment: Really? This doesn't work on 18.04 at all. I have only black screen and then goes X.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old post, but for others who need help, here's another way, which worked for me in Ubuntu 12.04 (after I got stuck with the Lubuntu splash):

1)  Open a terminal and type `gksu gedit`

2)  Enter your password and press enter

3)  Click "File" --> "Open"

4)  Click on "File System" and go to /lib/plymouth/themes.  Open the file "default.plymouth"

5)  Make it so that the file says this:

```
[Plymouth Theme]
Name=Ubuntu Logo
Description=A theme that features a blank background with a logo.
ModuleName=script

[script]
ImageDir=/lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo
ScriptFile=/lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.script
```

6)  Save the file and exit.

All done!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue with xubuntu 16.04 and managed to solve it by shutting down the computer / or rebooting (it doesn't matter), and as the shutdown screen appears(blue), I pressed F2 which made it show some Plymouth info in text and the loading screen was reactivated after that. Try it out and please tell me if it worked for you too. (Note: I accidentally deactivated my startup loading screen by pressing F2 at shutdown because my boot menu requires instant pressing when starting up)

Answer (score -2):

Here's an one liner command of the [abybaddi009's good answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/132181/25798):

```
sudo tee -a /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash <<<"FRAMEBUFFER=y"
```

Comment: This one liner wont work if /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash is writable only for root, it's better to run: `printf "FRAMEBUFFER=y" | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash`