# Ubuntu boot splash screen lost

Tags: plymouth

İ have installed Ubuntu 14.04.And boot splash screen is missing.There is only black screen after Grub and it opens Ubuntu directly.What can I do?

Comment: Maybe this one helps: http://askubuntu.com/questions/132120/how-to-recover-splash-screen?rq=1